# Problems with subclassing NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have spent the last day hunting down a dynamic storage issue and at the end of the trail I have no idea what is going on other than I must have misunderstood/missed something about subclassing NSString. Here is a much cut down and much instrumented sample that has the problem:

IDStringBug.h contains:

```
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
/*==================================*/
@interface IDStringBug:NSString {
  NSString      *_backingStore;
  NSArray   *path;
}
- (NSArray*) path;
- (void)     dealloc;
- (NSUInteger) length;
-(id)          initWithString:  (NSString*)  string;
-(unichar)     characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index;
@end
```

IDStringBug.m contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import "IDStringBug.h"

@implementation IDStringBug
- (NSArray*) path {
  printf ("Return ptr to IDString: %s\n", [_backingStore cString]);
  return path;}

- (void) dealloc {
  printf ("Release IDString: %s\n", [_backingStore cString]);
  printf ("Path count is %d\n", (int) [path retainCount]);
  [_backingStore  release];
  printf ("Apres _backinstore\n");
  printf ("Path count is %d\n", (int) [path retainCount]);
  [path release];
  printf ("After path release, done but for super\n");
  [super dealloc];
}

-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)string {
  if ((self = [self init])) {
    _backingStore = [[NSString stringWithString:string] copy];
  }
  path    = [_backingStore componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];

  printf ("Path count is %d\n", (int) [path retainCount]);
  return self;
}

-(NSUInteger) length {
  return [_backingStore length];
}
-(unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
  return [_backingStore characterAtIndex:index];
}
@end
```

bug.m contains:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <Foundation/NSAutoreleasePool.h>
#import "IDStringBug.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  IDStringBug *myids      = [IDStringBug stringWithString: @"a.b.c"];

  printf ("Path count is %d\n", (int) [[myids path] retainCount]);
  printf ("pool=%d\n",          (int) [pool autoreleaseCount]);

  [pool release];
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./bug
Path count is 1
Return ptr to IDString: a.b.c
Path count is 1
pool=7
Release IDString: a.b.c
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: why do u want to subclass it at all?

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, then `_path` is being assigned to an autoreleased object (the return value of `componentsSeparatedByString:`) and is deallocated prematurely. (Also, I've spotted an "après" in the place of an "after", are you francophone? :) )

Comment: That's not the question. You are only seeing a fraction of the class, the part that shows the bug.

Comment: I had quatrieme anne du la Francais dans le Ecole Secondaire. But that was a very long time ago. A tiny bit stuck. As to your question... I am on an Ubuntu Linux with as vanilla flavoured an install of Objc and support as possible. Just for completeness, I am using  -lobjc -lgnustep-base libraries and -fobjc-exceptions -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I /usr/include/GNUstep  compile switches.

Comment: Be sure you've read "Subclassing Notes" in the NSString reference.

Comment: Your comments below imply that you are using GNUStep on Linux?  That is critical to note in the question -- in the tags, even -- in that it'll change the tone of the answers considerably.

Answer (score 6):

This answer doesn't directly address your problem, but it will indirectly fix it and lead to a much more maintainable design pattern.

Don't subclass NSString.

Instead, use composition.

```
@interface PathString:NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *stringValue;
@property(strong) NSArray *pathValue;
... etc ...
@end
```

The actual crash is this:

```
  path    = [_backingStore componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
```

That method returns an autoreleased object and it is deallocated when the pool is drained, leaving a dangling reference.

As others have mentioned, `retainCount` is [utterly useless](http://www.whentouseretaincount.com).

Note that this is odd:

```
_backingStore = [[NSString stringWithString:string] copy];
```

That should simply be:

```
_backingStore = [string copy];
```

Your code is *technically* copying the string twice.  I say technically, because -- due to an implementation detail -- `_backingStore` will end up pointing to `string` (assuming `string` is an `NSString` and not an `NSMutableString`.

> I was very much an insider back in the NeXT days, but have been mostly
>   away or only used Objc base.

Aha! So was I, having started ObjC programming in 1989.

That'd explain where you are coming from a bit!

Instead of `retainCount`, an issue like this is quite easy to debug using zombies.   You can turn it on in the options pane of the scheme in Xcode.

The "whentouseretaincount.com" site links to an [article I wrote](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/) about retain count. You might find it interesting in that it also illuminates some details of memory management, in general.

> Apple document to the Linux GnuStep world

That is also critical to note in your questions. GNUStep is mostly just like Apple stuff, but is a little closer to the OpenStep world.   I can't remember if GNUStep has zombie detection, but I'd suspect it would.   Linux also has other memory debugging tools that are quite powerful.

`retainCount` is still going to be rife with fragility, but it is somewhat more stable when dealing with a single threaded, command line, tool.   You'll still need to watch out for autoreleased stuff, though.

Comment: I did!  As a NeXT Campus Consultant, I took developer training from him and then went on to act as an occasional teacher aid.

Comment: I was at CMU working in the music lab under Roger Dannenberg who did a lot of the Music Kit; I took the developer course (with Randy running the lab) for a Pgh startup in about 89; then went to Northern Ireland and was the campus consultant for QUB and was called on to teach OO programming for NeXT UK. So I knew a lot of the folks at NeXT. Still think it is the finest piece of Unix computer developer technology that was ever made.

Comment: Aha!  Small world!  I had an account on one of Roger's NeXT machines within days of the unveiling and spent a bunch of time in that lab teaching myself IB, NS, ObjC, etc...  and playing with the video harp & gesture interfaces.   I was the NeXT Campus Consultant for CMU for 4+ years, replaced by Joe Hollowood when I moved on to other adventures.

Comment: Then we must have met. I was the developer for the control panel application for the SensorFrame. Paul McAvinney was the developer of both.

Comment: btw, I dropped in on Roger just a couple months ago.

Comment: Cool! Definitely a small world and I'm sure we met!   Welcome back to ObjC!   If you ever make your way to CA area, feel free to ping me (my email is bbum@ <any random apple domain>).

Comment: What years btw? I left for Ireland in September '89.

Comment: I am in fact at the Mojave Spaceport in California right now :-)

Comment: I am also in contact with Dean Rubine and Chris Koenigsberg on a fairly regular basis.

Comment: Drop me an email, if you don't mind.   I think we may have just missed each other in the lab, then, as I believe Roger got the NeXT machine in Oct '89?  I know Dean, at least, was deep in Objective-C on the Sun 3/60 prior.

Comment: We had a Next with NeXtStep 0.8 on it, one of the first outside of the company itself I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an `NSArray` that has been autoreleased. That means it will have a retain count of 1, but that count will be decremented as soon as the autorelease pool is drained. Combine that with the `release` call in the IDStringBug dealloc, and you'll see that the array is being released one time too many.

In fact by the time the IDStringBug dealloc is called, the path array has already been deallocated. So when you try to determine the retain count (with the call to `[path retainCount]` you are attempting to access an object that no longer exists.

Comment: Okay, so that array would have to have its retain count incremented. Note that the retainCount call was what pointed my suspicions at the subclassing and I did suspect the path was being deallocated twice, I just could not see why.  Also, I read the 'never use retain count' article, however without retain counts I had even more issues with allocation failures. As an 'outsider' to the current FoundationKit world (I was very much an insider back in the NeXT days, but have been mostly away or only used Objc base) I want to ask cautiously about what sounds very much like a religious area ;-)

Comment: I might add that I have been using the Kochan book as a reference and although it talks much about alloc/dealloc and retain counts, I get the impression even he did not quite know how it worked... ;-)

Comment: For any object that you haven't created, you need to call `retain` if you want to take ownership of it, and `release` it when you are done with it. This is explained in more detail in the [Apple memory management documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). In this case, you want to take ownership of the array returned from `componentsSeparatedByString:` so you should retain it. You are already releasing it in your dealloc, so that part is correct.

Comment: The article about not using retain count is refering specifically to the `retainCount` method, because it returns misleading values. That's not saying you shouldn't use `retain` and `release` for reference counting.

Comment: The definition of 'that you did not create' is the interesting part. If I call an NSString method that returns a new string do I own it? If I put an argument in a method call as @"this is a new string" do I own it? In hindsight I can see the case with componentsSeparatedByString: since it is creating an array and returning it as a value. But in many other cases it seems a bit foggy.

Comment: Thanks for the note on retainCount. I suspect the person who put that up misunderstood my code... the retainCounts in it are nothing but debug scaffolding.

Comment: Read that link I gave you. If the method name begins with 'alloc', 'new', 'copy' or 'mutableCopy' then you own it, else not. A string received as a parameter in a function is not owned by the function (if it was, then you would have to release every string parameter you received in a function). Obviously these rules can't be guaranteed for code written by other people (including yourself), but that is the convention that should be followed.

Comment: NSString is one of the classes where it is hard to determine that as it does not have a new method per se. In its case would one presume that all the Class methods which create strings return you 'new' objects which you own?

Comment: @DaleAmon "it does not have a new method per se." - it does: `init`, `initWithString:`, `initWithCharacters:length:`, `initWithData:encoding:`, etc... Convenience class methods like `stringWithString:` return an autoreleased object which you **do not own,** but really, read the Advanced Memory Management Guide on developer.apple.com.

Comment: Yes, I just tracked down another issue that was precisely that case. [NSMutableString  stringWithString: @""] which I was using to init an instance var. A retain made the problem go away. As to the document, I actually skimmed through it a day or two ago but was uncertain as to the applicability of an Apple document to the Linux GnuStep world. From what you say, it *is*, so I will spend some time perusing it.

Comment: btw, thanks much for the pointers. Once I got that one cleared out, the rest of my major issues were pretty minor so I'll have something for show and tell at the review meeting tomorrow after all :-)